Send Ir command with Raspberry pi 3b+ in 2024

Good evening to all guys. I am writing to you because I need help with a project that I would like to carry out and I hope for your help. I'll briefly explain what I'm trying to do.
So via Raspberry Pi I want to control a hi-fi device via IR commands but this is becoming impossible... After reading many guides relating to LIRC where, the more time passed, the more impossible it was to use it, I decided to recreate the conditions when it was working, so using these two guides I tried to recreate the same conditions, hoping to make it work by also purchasing the shield that must be mounted on the pi:
https://devkimchi.com/2020/08/12/turning...ontroller/
https://spotpear.com/index/study/detail/id/843.html
https://github.com/mtraver/rpi-ir-remote
I only need the command sending part since I already have the .conf file downloaded from the LIRC database.
Except that when I go to launch the irsend command it is launched but nothing happens, and if I frame the LED with the camera it cannot be accessed. If there is anyone who has already had the opportunity to try it, can you give me a hand? The thing I don't understand is why if I try to read and memorize the commands it works and when I go to send them it doesn't. Should something be set before sending the command? For example, swap /dev/lirc0 and /dev/lirc1 when receiving and sending commands? If so, do you know how to set it?
I thank you in advance and, hoping for your kind help, I extend a big hello to the community

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

what does this mean? ... if I frame the LED with the camera it cannot be accessed ... what cannot be accessed? ... do you get an error when you try to access it?

Sorry !! Wrong translate  I wanted to say that if I frame it with the phone's camera the led doesn't blink. It depends on the filter on the camera?

when I have to launch the command with irsend do I have to do something first? or once the command is launched it should go? Could the fact that it doesn't work depend on the parameters set on the downloaded lirc file? but I think since the file is in the database so I think it's working. The file of my device is Denon RC-220

wrong translate ... why haven't you corrected it?

You don't need LIRC! As you have found, it is difficult to use. It is unnecessary since infrared is now handled by the kernel. There a couple of posts about receiving IR that might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70304099 https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/753802/321108

I'm sorry if I explained my problem badly, now I'll try to be more clear, hoping you can help me.
Hardware: Raspberrypi 3B+

List item
  220ohm and 10K
  transistor BC547
  led ir



Software: Raspbian 9 Strecht , Kernel Version 4.19.66-v7+ , Lirc Version 0.9.4c
/boot/config.txt

dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=22
dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=23


sudo nano /etc/lirc/lirc_options.conf

nodaemon        = False
driver          = default
device          = /dev/lirc0

I only made these two changes. I took the lircd.conf file from the lirc database. The device I need to check is RC-220. For the connections I used a bredboard as seen in the photo. The problem is that when I use the irsend command nothing happens. If I frame with the camera I don't see the LED light up. I did a test by connecting a simple green LED and when I send the command it lights up so I think the Raspberry is sending the command.
Mi sono basato su questa guida:
https://github.com/mtraver/rpi-ir-remote

how does this answer the question?
